# es6 class methods can't reach this instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, this

So I made a class and have no idea why I can't reach `this` instance inside one method.

So in my router I'm calling the method like this

```
import Emails from '../controllers/emails'
import router from 'express'
....
route.post('/', Emails.setupEmail)
```

so after calling `POST` method it calls `setupEmail` method but it crashes with the message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableEmailTypes' of undefined

and the code of class:

```
class Emails {

constructor() {
    this.availableEmailTypes = ['registration', 'forgot-password', 'two-factor']
}

setupEmail(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.type || !req.body.type.include(this.availableEmailTypes)) {
        return res.status(422).send({ success: false, message: 'Invalid email type' })
    }

    switch (req.body.type) {
        case 'registration':
            break
    }
}

}

export default new Emails()
```

so the main question is why I can't reach array created on constructor?

Comment: Can I ***strongly*** recommend not exporting an **instance** of the class (`new Emails`) and importing it using the class name (`Emails`)?! Talk about tripping people up reading/maintaining the code later... (For that matter, there's no point to the `Emails` class at all if you're just going to have one instance; just use an object.)

Comment: What @T.J.Crowder is saying + if you do Server-Side Rendering and at some point someone decides to change that value at run-time you'll end up mixing request data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `this` and how it's dynamically bound based on call-time context. When you call `Emails.setupEmail`, inside of it `this` won't be the `Emails` instance you export. Either use arrow functions to define your methods *or* `bind(Emails)` when you call it.

Comment: yeah that helped, never thought that arrow functions could be so important at such a place!